# TyperError: Team is Not a Constructor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, model-view-controller, mongoose

I'm working on a basic website made in Express. I'm using MongoDB for the backend. At this time, I'm attempting to populate MongoDB with the following code. However, I am recieving this error.

**var team = new Team({**

**TypeError: Team is not a constructor**

Create Team Function

```
function createTeam(team_name) {
    var team = new Team({
        TeamName: team_name
    });
    team.save().then(function() {
            console.log(team_name);
      }  );
}

Model/Schema File.

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var teamSchema = new Schema({
     TeamName: String
});
var Team = mongoose.model('Team', teamSchema);
module.export = Team;
```

It's my first time using Express/MongoDB so any tips and assistance is greatly appriciated.

Comment: Did you import your `Team` model correctly in the other file where you use it?

Comment: I imported it the following: 
`var Team = require('./models/teamModel');`

Comment: Update your code properly with file name as reference in your question

Comment: I identified the issue. It was essentially a typo at the module export. Instead of module.exports, I had module.export hence why it wasn't identifying the Schema. Thanks for the assistance.